# Given the limit of a function divided by a number, find the limit of that function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm on my fourth hour of calculus today and the home stretch, I just need to learn a few more concepts. This problem in particular is confusing to me, I was hoping someone could give me a hint as to where to begin.

If $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 8$, find $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) \ne 0$, then what will happen to $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I've just edited what I wrote so that it makes sense. Is it clearer now?

Comment: When $x$ is close to $0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is close to $8$, so $f(x)$ is close to $8x$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the limit of a product is equal to the product of the limits. That is, $\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)g(x)] = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)*\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$. I think this is the hint G.T.R. was trying to give.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is finite, $f(x)$ must be $0$ in order to prevent the $x$ in the denominator from making the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$.

Comment: "I was hoping someone could give me a hint as to where to begin"

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$f(x) =\frac{f(x)}{x} \times x$